How many players to consider for probability calculation
if I play on a table with 6 players, websites like https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/poker-odds ask you for the number of opponents.
What should I fill in there, the number of opponents initially at the table (5), or the number of active players?
The simple answer could be to put the active players, but I would argue that it's not giving accurate estimations. As soon as the opponents are not either drunk or random bots, the probability is high that only the best hole cards remain out of the 5.
Of course, some will be bluffing though, but shouldn't the conservative number of players still be 5?
Another problem is that if someone bets and 4 opponents fold, my probability will mechanically (and dramatically) increase, but in fact 5 opponents have seen and reacted to the play, not 2.
How, and when, should I adjust the number of opponents?

Your point about "inactive" (folded) players being relevant is a good one that is usually ignored. It is common for poker theorists to treat a scenario where there are (say) 5 players in total, and the first player (the hijack) raises, equivalently to a full-ring game where the hijack raises. As you point out, in the latter case it is more likely that low cards have been folded than high ones, which marginally increases the probability that the remaining cards are high. The practical impact on the maths is very small, though, and (though I haven't checked) I expect this solver ignores it.

Number of opponents is always calculated as the number of players who are still in the hand. People folding has little to no factor on these calculations as you don't know their cards. If you knew exactly what they folded 100% factor it in, but you never will unless you're watching a live stream or poker TV table where they have either cameras on the cards or RFID cards. To answer your question calculations are only done against the number of opponents still in the hand as active. Assuming we don't know inactive players cards.

To be clear, I'm not saying there isn't value in understanding someone's range and understanding that if they fold in early position we can assume a lot of thrash is folded. I just want to be clear I'm not saying there is no value. However you're asking about a equity calculator, and I am saying in pure equity calculations and calculators it is irreverent (like what you have linked). A good example of this is AK off vs 5 random hands has 27% equity preflop, however you're not playing against 5 hands, but hopefully only 1 (65% equity) or 2(48% equity).

preflop yes I understand, but let's say that 3 players fold preflop, leaving 2 opponents active. The approach I'm taking is that I would simulate for many random 5 hands which 2 are best preflop, and consider only my avg equity vs these 2-best-out-of-5 hands. Then if 1 player folds on the flop, I would consider my last opponent as the best out of these 2 (themselves the best 2 out of 5). I like that idea because I'd be using the whole history of the hand and hopefully get more realistic results
For example, on the flop i'm not playing 2 random opps but 2 best out of 5.
Think this is valid?

say that, for the same example, on the flop we have 2 hearts and 1 spade, then the turn and the river are spades. using this approach i would know that there is little probability that there's a suit of spades in the remaining best-of-two-best-of-five, because on the flop, opponents with 2 hearts had better hands on average than those with spades... this is not, I think, captured in the random method of only active players, and isn't this also arguably closer to how conservative, low-level players will play?

just to precise: The approach I'm taking is that I would simulate for many random 5 hands which 2 are best preflop, and consider only my avg equity vs these 2-best-out-of-5 hands on the flop. Then if 1 player folds on the flop, I would consider my last opponent as the best out of these 2 on the flop (themselves the best 2 out of 5 preflop) and calculate my equity on the turn vs him. In fact these simulations would implicitly assign a kind of range to the remaining players
